# C++ : calling an Abstract method inside an abstract class

Tags: c++, abstract-class, virtual

I have an abstract class containing two classes (one abstract, one non-abstract).
I want to call the abstract method from the non abstract method.

Here that's what I want to do :

```
class abstractClass { 
     public:
     virtual void abstractMethod() = 0 ;
     void nonAbstractMethod();
}
```

in .cpp :

```
void abstractClass::nonAbstractMethod() {
     abstractClass::abstractMethod();

     /* ... */

}
```

Is it possible in c++?

The problem here is that the nonAbstracMethod isn't static, so I can't call it without instance of object. But this is an abstract class! I can't instantiate it... How can I manage with this?

I often do this in java but I didn't find how in c++...

Comment: Is this just a puzzle, or are you trying to *do* something?

Comment: Simply don't qualify it with the type name: `abstractMethod();`

Comment: Just call the method without the classname qualifier: `abstractMethod();`

Comment: It is not possible to call a abstract method because it does not have any implementation. Why do you need this? What should do abstract method?

Comment: @AngeloDM: That's only true in constructors and destructors

Comment: @MooingDuck Please, could you make an example?

Comment: @AngeloDM: (It's possible I misunderstood your comment).  You can _call_ an "abstract" method and the implementation of the most derived type will be called, except in constructors and destructors.  However, one could argue that you were referring to the implementation associated with the abstract base class.  In truth, even an abstract base class can have implementations for abstract methods, and those can be called manually, or will be used in constructors and destructors.  `=0` means there may or may not be an implementation for this base, not that there is no implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Concrete subclasses will provide their version of `abstractMethod()`. Thorugh the virtual call mechanism, when `nonAbstractMethod()` is called with an instance of a concrete subclass, the correct implementation of `abstractMethod()` will be called. That is, if you don't qualify the method with a type name (which you can do, as long as you also provide the implementation in `abstractClass`*).

You should remember to make the destructor in `abstractClass` virtual, so the proper one is called when an object is deleted through an `abstractClass` pointer.

Also, you should know that memeber function are statically bound in constructor\destructors. Otherwise you'd call methods expecting parts of an object that are yet to be constructed or were already destructed.

This is object oriented programming 101

<sub>*Yes, pure virtual functions can have implementation.</sub>

Comment: @MooingDuck, did I catch your drift?

Comment: I have destructor/constructor. I didn't put this in my code to be  clear. Sorry. It was just an example, my code is more complicated.

Comment: when I don't write anything before abstactMethod(), he doesn't recognize it :/
I already tried this.

Comment: @Kostinen, is there a missing `;` after the class definition in your actual code code as well? Because upon fixing it, it builds without a hitch http://ideone.com/9tPcJE

Comment: Thank for your answer :)
I didn't try the code I put here for the example. My code is more complicated and was ok when I just used one abstract method, but I want to factorize some code in the non abstract method so that I don't have to remember to put this in the every heritated class (or someone who wants to create a class heritated from abstract class).
So my code ok! (I have 5 years of coding : I would not ask this question if it was just for a ";" :) ).

Comment: @Kostinen, experience notwithstanding, your sample code should demonstrate the exact problem you are facing, and raise the exact same error. Otherwise any attempt to help you is pointless. You should read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Oh sorry!! I missed this.

Comment: It works when I implement the function in .h (not in the .cpp).
That's weird because I'm in a big project and I always defined my functions in .cpp. That could be an "include" problem but the destructor implementation is in the .cpp and there is no problem with this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an instance, but this is an abstract class. So the instance will actually have to be a subclass that implements the pure virtual method.

And your syntax will just be:

```
void abstractClass::nonAbstractMethod() {
     abstractMethod();
    /* ... */
}
```

So it will look like this:

```
class ConcreteClass : public abstractClass {
  virtual void abstractMethod() { //do something 
  }
};

int main() {
  abstractClass *a = new ConcreteClass();
  a->nonAbstractMethod();
  return 0;
}
```

Also, in C++, remember that destructors of classes intended to be used as a base class (like this abstract one) should always have virtual destructors, in case they are destroyed via a pointer-to-base or reference-to-base.

And if you choose to make the destructor the one function that is pure virtual when defining an abstract class, the pure virtual destructor must nevertheless also have an implementation (although it may not have to do anything; empty is fine if there are no resource4s to release.)

Comment: It would be good to add a sentence about constructors/destructors

Answer (score 1):

> I often do this in java but I didn't find how in c++...

This is the bit I don't quite understand about your question. If you know how to do this in Java, then what exactly is the problem in C++? All you need to do is add a virtual destructor and consider making the abstract method private (rather than protected as you would in Java).

Java:

```
public abstract class Example {
    protected abstract void abstractMethod();
    public void nonAbstractMethod() {
        abstractMethod();
    }
}
```

C++:

```
class Example {
private:
    virtual void abstractMethod() = 0;
public:
    void nonAbstractMethod() {
        abstractMethod();
    }
    virtual ~Example() {}
};
```

Hint: do some Google research on "Template Method Design Pattern" or "Non-Virtual Interface Idiom".

Comment: It's exactly what I already tried! So ok we can do that in c++, I'm relieved :)
The problem is maybe somewhere else.

Comment: *private abstract method*, really?

Comment: @Yola: Yes. The abstractness of a function refers to its implementation; the access specifier refers to how it is called. These are two different concerns. Unfortunately, most other languages mix them up and forbid private abstract methods, but C++ does it right.